# Add numbers from three different queries together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I am getting average values for different past 3, 6 and 10 months.From following queries

```
select SUM(GrossAmount)/10 as Averageten  
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -10, GETDATE()) 

select SUM(GrossAmount)/6 as Averagesix  
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) 

select SUM(GrossAmount)/3 as Averagethree  
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
```

I get three different values for example:

```
1200.22
2300.22
4500
```

I want to get the average of those three values like this

```
(1200.22 + 2300.22 + 4500) / 3
```

How can I add values from these separate queries.

Comment: what do you mean by add values from these separate queries can you elaborate it

Answer (score 3):

Use union to merge three queries and then do average

```
select avg(Averageten)
from
(select SUM(GrossAmount)/10 as Averageten  
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -10, GETDATE()) 
union
select SUM(GrossAmount)/6 
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) 
union 
select SUM(GrossAmount)/3   
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
)a
```

OR you can use conditional aggregation to find the values as you query is from same table with different condition

```
select ((sum(case when CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -10, GETDATE()) then GrossAmount end)/10)
+(sum(case when CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) then GrossAmount end)/6)
+(sum(case when CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) then GrossAmount end)/3))/3 
from tablename
```

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
(
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -10, GETDATE()) THEN GrossAmount END) / 10 +
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,  -6, GETDATE()) THEN GrossAmount END) /  6 +
    SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,  -3, GETDATE()) THEN GrossAmount END) /  3
) / 3 AS [10, 6, 3 Average]
FROM Table
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -10, GETDATE()) -- this covers all three cases
```

Comment: You might want `else 0`s to be safe in case there is no older data.